# Why isn't Google Apps Script considered Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

On [Google Apps Script Documentation Overview](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview) it says:

> **Google Apps Script is a scripting language based on JavaScript** that lets you do new and cool things with G Suite products like Docs, Sheets, Slides, and Forms.

But it looks to me like it's just plain Javascript with an API.

Comment: See [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Apps_Script)

Comment: There are Apps Script services used to interact with different Google products.  The Apps Script services are not JavaScript.  A mix of Apps Script services and JavaScript is used.  If you create a Web App, dialog box or sidebar, then you will also use HTML, CSS and the DOM.  Plus you could use many different frameworks with HTML.  So, you could use a mix of many different things to create an app.  Apps Script services use Classes, Properties and Methods.  Those Classes, Properties and Methods are not JavaScript, they are Apps Script services.

Comment: But appending more Classes, Properties and Methods only, doesn't make it an API over javascript, Instead of a new language?

Comment: It doesn't only append more it removes stuff as well and runs server-side.